# c++ how to read and write within a file

Tags: c++, windows, text

i want to make a text based rpg game, but ive run into a problem, im fairly "new" to c++, know a few concepts but still learning.
So what i want to know is; how do i open a file and edit the values in it?
say i have a file called health, for my characters health and its set to 100. I know you can just subtract the variable by the damage you set the monsters to do, but i dont know how i store the health and edit it, while my program goes along.

ie. this is the farthest i got:

```
ifstream objectFile("health.txt");
string health;
double NoH;

cout << "welcome" << endl;
objectFile >> health >> NoH;
cout << health << ' ' << NoH - 15;
```

NoH = Number of health. So far all my program does, is read the file, and subtract 15 from 100 because thats the damage the monster do. But how do i make it "take out" the value and subtract 15 from it? then store it back so it's 85, and next time i get hit its 65 for example etc, so it makes it the objective of the game is about surviving, ie avoiding getting hit and stuff. i mean avoiding your hp to reach 0, but also i want to learn how to implement simple text based creatures you can kill, by letting their hp reach 0.
thanks

Comment: You will probably have a lot more state information than just this in the game.  As part of your design you should be thinking about how you want to represent all of this data and how (and when) you persist it.  Many games do not save to disk on every change, but only periodically (or when the user chooses to), with state primarily only kept in memory.

Comment: One option is to use an INI file format. Read its contents into local variables at startup, modify those variables as the game is played, and write the entire list of updated values back to the INI file just before you exit (replacing the original INI file completely).

Comment: @joe yea it was just a sample code, im going to implement functions and classes aswell, but primarily i want to know how to read and write output to a file. And what exactly do you mean by "state primarily kept in memory" if you could elaborate on that please :)

Comment: I agree with @Joe! Even if there will be less state informations, it would be reasonable, to keep the information in memory primarily!

Comment: @cppnewb I mean -- you have classes, objects, variables in C++.  Store your information in them.  Have a set of routines that take those structures and can persist them and read them from disk, but don't use disk storage as your go-between within your code to share information.

Comment: As a side note/hint: Always seralze/load(deserialze) from/to the complete in memory model as requested.

Comment: hmm i'm probably in over my head on this project now.. :P but how do i store info in them? like say int health = 100; and then when i get hit in my game i subtract the hp? without having a file to read from? will that keep the hp at a consistent level, like this: first hit i lose 15 hp the it goes to 85, next hit 20 so its 65 and so on

Answer (score 0):

what about using ini /properties file?
or using json?

if you are making rpg, player save the values (hp,mp,item, map(x,y) etc) to file when saving the game? and the rest of the time should store/calculate those value in memory I guess.

about json
https://code.google.com/p/vjson/

about ini file
http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/

Comment: hmm, its not gonna be a graphical rpg or anything, just a console text based one, like the old books where you had an option and if u chose one you went to another page where you read on. something like that.. but yea, what do you mean with store/calculate those values in memory? can you give me an example code? and thanks i will look into the links

Comment: in memory just mean the variables, char*, int, float whatever...so you store the values in the variables, and you can save or load to a file when you type a "Save" command, of coz you can save every time that any of those value changed

Comment: but will i be able to change the values as my game goes along? ie i start at 100hp, then i subtract 15 hp because thats the monsters damage, then next time i subtract 15 again and it will remember that my hp was 85 and not 100 as the initial value is? if that makes sense

Comment: you should have loops/routines of differ state, like player round(user doing something, move on map, hit a monster, open a door, etc) and some calculate from the variables, store it back-> NPC round (Hit player, run away, etc) and then (some calculate from the variables, store it back) again.....and that would be a loop, until the player HP 0 or all monsters are killed for example.

Comment: ah yea that totally makes sense now.. im just tired as hell cant think str8 lol.. also forgot about what i can do with classes, i.e store values and whatnot.. i will make a mini project tomorrow, but for now thx for the help man